# OpenVPN browser tunneling

Tags: cyanogenmod, browser, openvpn

I hope I do not say silly things, or discounted, but I'm a newbie, at least for vpn.

I want use my browser to connect on my corporate intranet via VPN connection, but I'm not able to do it.

Someone can help me?

Some information:
I tried 2 way to confgure OpenVPN:

---

I've configured OpenVPN via openvpn-settings apps (using pre-created cert files located on /openvpn ). The .ovpn config files sound like

```
 port yyyy
dev tun
\#dev-node ovpn
proto tcp-client
remote xxx1.xxxx.it yyyy
remote xxx2.xxxx.it yyyy
remote xxx3.xxxx.it jjj
remote xxx4.xxxx.it jjj
ping 30

persist-tun persist-key

tls-client
ca xxx.ca.crt
cert xxx.aaaa.bbbb.crt
key xxx.aaaa.bbbb.key

ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
pull
verb 5
```

I connect to VPN with no problems, and I can use for example ssh to connect on my corporate Linux server.

---

I've created a VPN from Menu->Settings-> Wireless & network-> VPN settings -> add VPN-> add VPN OpenVPN and set parameters according with the previous .ovpn config file
I connect also to VPN with no problems, and I can use for example ssh to connect on my corporate linux server.

---

On both cases I'm not able to browse intranet. So I checked the IP address I go out with, pointing to http://m.showip.net/, and it displayed my provider IP, not the assigned VPN IP!
Is it possible that VPN don't tunnel all traffic? Maybe I need to change the default gateway somehow?

My O.S. is

```
Android 2.3.7
kernel 2.6.35.14-nFinity
ROM Cyanogenmod 7.1.0.1 stable
Phone HTC Wildfire (Buzz)
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have this `--redirect-gateway` in your configuration file.

That option is documented on the [OpenVPN man page](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/69-openvpn-21.html)

> ```
>  --redirect-gateway
>
> Automatically execute routing commands to cause all outgoing IP traffic to be redirected over the VPN.
>
> This option performs three steps:
>
>     Create a static route for the --remote address which forwards to the pre-existing default gateway. This is done so that (3) will not create a routing loop.
>
>     Delete the default gateway route.
>
>     Set the new default gateway to be the VPN endpoint address (derived either from --route-gateway or the second parameter to --ifconfig when --dev tun is specified).
>
> When the tunnel is torn down, all of the above steps are reversed so that the original default route is restored.
> ```